# User access restriction on BLE device

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am using iOS CoreBluetooth SDK to access several BLE devices. 
What would be a general approach to restrict access to devices based on user accounts.

e.g. user of type x should only be allowed to access of BLE devices of type y

Here are few approaches which I came up with

1. Create a user type Service and characteristic in BLE device. But this would require connection to device and I want to hide the visibility of the device itself.
2. Use the device Id of the BLE device to map the user access. But apparently CoreBluetooth SDK does not give access to deviceId.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking, but you will need to implement any restrictions in your app itself.  Based on the user type that is authenticated in your app you can scan for peripherals advertising the appropriate services (i.e. service type Y for user type X, service type A for user type B)

Comment: @Paulw11 scanning based on services will work great but currently  I have services common across devices. So **device type** relation is basically of type user account and BLE device association.

Comment: As long as there is one unique service that corresponds with a user type surely you can scan for that service.  Once you have discovered a device you can discover any additional services that are required.  If there isn't a unique service (and you can't create one) then you will need to connect to the device and determine if you want to proceed

Comment: You can also separate the devices by deviceName, so you don't actually need the deviceId.